# How to inject injection token to constructor of component in unit test

Tags: angular

I have injection token:

`export const IS_SEO_PAGE = new InjectionToken<boolean>('accommodation.seo');`

I use it in component

`constructor(@Inject(IS_SEO_PAGE) private isSeo: boolean,`

but when I try to inject it to test it fails with error 
`Can't resolve all parameters`

this is test:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ TranslateModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [ StickyNavComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: IS_SEO_PAGE, useValue: true }],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create', inject([IS_SEO_PAGE], (isSeo: boolean) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out import order of InjectionToken is important, you want to import token after all your imports

Comment: would you be able to show how you did it? I have same problem with the injection.

Comment: hi @Nikita can you tell us what order are you talking about, is it from the @angular/core alone or  is it after all the other interface imports?